# JFrame setIconImage() not working outside Intellij

Tags: java

It works perfectly when I run application inside IDE, but when I build artifact it throws NPE.
NPE is thrown on this line

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(ConnectF.class.getResource("/cool.PNG")).getImage());
```

Also "cool.png" is compiled in same jar with all other classes
[cool.jpg placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAxZM.png)

[Also final jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOZY7.png)

Comment: `cool.png` and `cool.PNG` are not the same thing.  jar entries are case sensitive.  I suspect it worked in your IDE because you’re running on Windows, where file names, unlike .jar entry names, are not case sensitive.

Comment: I'd also check that the image has been included within your resulting Jar. There just zip files, so you can change the extension to .zip and unzip it to check

Comment: I already done that (picture is under "Also final jar file"). Also solution from @VGR works, thank you guys